# Como hacer un Formulario en android y que se envie los datos a un correo?

Tags: android-studio, formularios

Hola estoy creando una app  android y quiero crear un formulario de contacto que se envié a mi correo me gustaría que me ayudaran soy nuevo en esto. muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

esta es una forma de realizar el envio:

```
 Log.i("Send email", "");
  String[] TO = {"emaildestino@correo.com"};
  String[] CC = {"emailconcopia@correo.com"};
  Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

  emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
  emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, TO);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, CC);
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "encabezado");
  emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "usuario@tuemail.com");

  try {
     startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Enviando Email..."));
     Log.i("termina envio de email...", "");
  }
  catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No existe cliente Email instalado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Para tu formulario, puedes crear una vista con varios EditText en los cuales escribes los valores necesarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí tienes un ejemplo en español:

http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/curso-android-enviar-emails/

Comment: Hola Elenasys lo que me gustaría es un formulario que cualquier usuario coloque sus datos: nombre, email, teléfono, etc y sea enviado a mi correo  si me podrías ayudar te lo agradecería he intentado de todo y no me funciona. El código que me haz mandado el usuario debe colocar el correo donde se envía y no es lo ando buscando. muchas gracias y disculpa espero su respuesta